# Implementing Home Grown Plugins for a Python Service

Tags: python, plugins, importerror

I am writing a simple scheduling service. I don't want to hard-code all of the tasks it can schedule and instead would like to support plugins that can be dropped in a folder and loaded dynamically at runtime.

My plan is to have a JSON file (or any configuration file) that maps a task name to the location of a Python file (a module) which will have a class called `Plugin`. Pretty simple I thought. When someone schedules a task to run, they pass the task name and the time to run it. When the time elapses, the plugin is loaded (or reloaded) and is ran with any additional arguments passed to the scheduler.

I have been looking at the `imp` module to see how to load modules at runtime. I am not sure whether I want to list plugins using their physical location (file system path) or to use their module names like you'd see in a `import` statement. It seems `imp` wants to use physical location.

I got two different versions of this code "working". Here is one that uses `importlib`:

```
    pluginName = self.__pluginLookup[pluginName]
    module = import_module(pluginName)
    module = reload(module)  # force reload

    plugin = module.Plugin()
    return plugin
```

This is one I wrote using `imp`:

```
    path = self.__pluginLookup[pluginName]
    path, moduleName = split(path)
    moduleName, extension = splitext(moduleName)

    file, path, description = find_module(moduleName, [path])
    with file:
        module = load_module(moduleName, file, path, description)

    plugin = module.Plugin()
    return plugin
```

The problem I am running into is handling dependencies. If I have a `plugin.py` file that depends on a `dependency.py` file in the same folder, saying `import dependency` doesn't seem to work. Instead, it looks up the dependency from the `PYTHONPATH`.

How can I make the imports relative to the plugins themselves?

Comment: What is the file/directory structure of your plugins?

Comment: I am thinking of having a `plugins` directory under at the current working directory. Under that, people can either place .py files or they can place sub-directories for packages. I will probably require that they include a `__init__.py` file for directories they want treated as packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append `path` to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path)
```

where `path` is the directory containing the dependency.py.

Comment: I thought I could recursively import the modules. After getting something to work, I realized I couldn't determine the order that they depend on one another. I'd have to import them in reverse order. So, long story short, I just added folders with `__init__.py` files to the  `sys.path`, like you recommended. Much easier and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `plugins` directory with an `__init__.py`, you can add that directory to `sys.path`.  Then modules inside there can do `from . import dependency` to import another plugin.  Or, if the plugin is itself a subpackage (i.e., a directory with its own `__init__.py`) then it can do `from . import dep` to import a dependency within the same plugin, or `from .. import dep` to import a dependency from the global plugins directory.  With this setup you don't even need to use `imp` or the like; you can use the `__import__` function, which works by module name.

One possible wrinkle, though, is you say the plugins directory will be "under the current working directory".  What does that mean exactly?  You mean you want people to be able to add plugins anywhere on the drive and still use them?  It would be better to have one central plugins directory for your app, and add that to `sys.path`, and tell people to put their plugins there.

Comment: I am all for a single repository. I just want to make sure someone can drop a single plugin file or an entire package if they wanted. My guess is that plugins will be very simple, so won't have a lot of dependencies, but I don't want to assume that.